# What is this dial on the organ in the Berliner Dom?

Tags: organ

**What is this dial on the organ in the Berliner Dom?**

I am guessing that the dial may have something to do with air pressure but why would it be needed and what units do the numbers represent?

[image]

**Here is the performance where the dial is first shown - Warning Loud!"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be a crescendo indicator dial.
It is used to know what is the current position of the crescendo pedal on some organ.

[image: Here] Another example. (Image from https://pipeorgandatabase.org/organ/16221)

Comment: Thanks - that sounds highly likely although I haven't yet been able to confirm online that this particular organ has a crescendo pedal.

Comment: The [Sauer organ in the Berliner Dom](https://www.berlinerdom.de/musik/musikangebote/orgeln-am-berliner-dom/sauer-orgel/) has a crescendo pedal.  That's the "Registercrescendo" in the "Spielhilfen" listed on the German language page.  The Sauer organ has 113 registers.  The dial is marked to 104, so I would assume that only 104 of the total registers are connected to the crescendo pedal.  The display shows how many of the available registers are selected.

Comment: @JRE - Thanks, that's good enough for me!